# Cassandra cluster manager (ccm) on docker

Tags: cassandra, docker, containers

I have installed ccm as per this [link](http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-ccm-cassandra-cluster-manager/) on a docker image.
For using different containers to host a datacenter each, I have to invoke 'ccm create' and 'ccm start' on the same image. 
In other words, I need multiple containers to be up using same image.

If I try these 2 calls:

```
...:    docker run nav064/ubuntuccm:v4 /bin/sh lccm.sh DC_SLC 5 
Current cluster is now: DC_SLC
Cluster: 'DC_SLC'
-----------------
node1: UP
node3: UP
node2: UP
node5: UP
node4: UP

..:    docker run nav064/ubuntuccm:v4 /bin/sh lccm.sh DC_BLR 5
Current cluster is now: DC_SLC
Cluster: 'DC_BLR'
-----------------
node1: UP
node3: UP
node2: UP
node5: UP
node4: UP
```

This is my lccm.sh

```
ccm create $1 -v 2.1.3
ccm populate -n $2
ccm start
ccm status
```

And look for all containers

```
docker ps
```

I don't see any containers running.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it, but I think the problem could be that the `lccm.sh` ends after creating the cluster. Any Docker container will ends after its main process (that is the process with PID 1 and the one which is launched with `docker run`). You should run daemonized processes to avoid this. One fast attempt could be using this `lccm.sh`

```
ccm create $1 -v 2.1.3
ccm populate -n $2
ccm start
ccm status
while true; do sleep 1000; done
```